# Copy constructor traverse through linked list. implementation

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, linked-list, copy-constructor

I am attempting to copy the entire linked list in my copy constructor, however I continue to get access
Why isn't my copy construction working properly? 
errors:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00AE506C in program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.
```

copy constructor

```
NodeSLList::NodeSLList(NodeSLList & list)
{
    head = list.head;
    IntNode *tmp = head;
    cout << "copy constructor called" << endl;

    int size;
    size = list.GetSize();

    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
        tmp->data= list.RetrieveNode(i).data;
        tmp->next = list.RetrieveNode(i).next;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
```

in main

```
NodeSLList list2 (list1);
cout << "cout << list2 " << endl;
cout << list2 << endl;
```

The error occurs at `cout << list2 << endl;` since the cop constructor did not properly copy the linked list.

Comment: Is there a reason why you start your loops at `1`?  In C++, the first element is (usually) `0`.  Also, do you have a function that adds a node to the back of the list?  If so, the copy constructor is much more simple than what you coded.

Comment: the way i set up the linked list is 1 to N

Comment: I updated my comment.  If you have a function that adds to the back of the list, then use it in the copy constructor.  As to starting your count at 1 instead of 0, many times starting at 1 is a source of off-by-1 bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is this:

```
head = list.head;
IntNode *tmp = head;
```

You should *not* be copying pointer values.  You will wind up with two pointers pointing to the same memory.  Both objects should have different `head` values.

If you have a function that adds a node to your linked list, then you can use it in the copy constructor to avoid this.  Here is an example:

```
NodeSLList::NodeSLList(const NodeSLList & list) : head(0)
{
    int size;
    size = list.GetSize();
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
        addData(list.RetrieveNode(i).data);
}
```

This requires that you have a function similar to `addData` that adds a new node using the data passed in.  Note that this tests your `addData` function to ensure it works properly.  The copy constructor just calls it in a loop.

Finally, you also need an assignment operator to go along with the copy constructor (and also a destructor).  The assignment operator can be written using the copy constructor and destructor as helper functions (i.e. the `copy/swap` idiom).